# Execução de rotina em segundo plano via HangFire (ASP.NET WebForms)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms, hangfire

estou precisando fazer uma execução em segundo plano no meu sistema. Para isso, eu encontrei a ferramenta HangFire. Fiz as configurações conforme a documentação e estou obtendo o erro: Valor não pode ser nulo. Nome do parâmetro: method

Abaixo meu código:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
    private BackgroundJobServer _backgroundJobServer;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var storage = new SqlServerStorage(connectionString); // db_HangFire is the connection string for Sql Server DB used as Job Storage for HangFire for processing 
        var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions();
        _backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer(options, storage);
        _backgroundJobServer.Start(); // start BackgroundJobServer process
        JobStorage.Current = storage; // assign the storage to Current

    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _backgroundJobServer.Dispose(); // Dispose the BackgroundJobServer Object
    }
}


namespace HangFireWebForms
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnEnqueue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => HangFireTask(this.txtMensagem.Text));
        }

        private void HangFireTask(string message)
        {
            this.lblHangFireResultTask.Text = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde está recebendo esse erro?

Comment: O erro acontece bem na hora de executar BackgroundJob.Enqueue()

Comment: E onde está a HangfireTask está aonde?

Comment: Amigo, não sei bem o que está querendo saber. Há um formulário HangFireWebForms em que coloquei um botão e no click ele deveria enfileirar o método HangFireTask que está declarado no mesmo formulário. Pode ver pelo meu código que o HangFireTask está implementado logo abaixo do click.

Comment: Na verdade esse erro está parecendo algum detalhe de configuração, além do `HangFireTask()` estar definido como privado, não aparenta ter outro erro. Você verificou se ele criou as tabelas no banco de dados indicado?